# Fetch Remote Data using Guzzle

Tags: php, http, guzzle

I want to fetch data from webpages using Guzzle. I have written the following code:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://yandex.ru']);

$response = $client->request('GET');

$body = $response->getBody();

echo $body;
```

But I receive Fatal Error when I run this code on my localhost.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\Xampp\htdocs\Guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187 Stack trace: #0 C:\Xampp\htdocs\Guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #1 C:\Xampp\htdocs\Guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #2 C:\Xampp\htdocs\Guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #3 C:\Xampp\htdocs\Guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle in C:\Xampp\htdocs\Guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187
```

The problem is that when I delete the last three lines of my code, it works well, so the issue is with request. Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: change defaults verify to false and see if it works . **new GuzzleClient(['defaults' => [
    'verify' => false
]]);**

Comment: I just tried , but it doesn't help

Comment: Did you try specifying the 'verify'=>false option at the request level?
  http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#verify

Comment: @Gabriel your solution maybe somehow helped because now I get much shorter fatal error

Comment: I just changed ['base_uri' => 'https://yandex.ru'] to ['base_uri' => 'http://httpbin.org'] and it worked perfectly. Could anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This error occur when the curl.cainfo and openssl.cafile config
>   properties of the php.ini file, do not target any valid certificate
>   that allow you to create connection with **ssl** as they will be invalid.

With `https://yandex.ru` you connect over ssl, but not in `httpbin.org` case. That's why you don't get the SSL certificate problem.

As a solution, I recommend you this [article](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/196/xampp-wampp-php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate).